# I have a problem with my face Recognition project. In the MySQL database, there are columns named (Name, Id, Roll No), Information doesn't show up

Tags: python, mysql, face-recognition

It is a Face recognition project writing in Python.
I am Trying to get information which i have saved in **My SQL** database tables.
It is Recognizing the faces but not showing the information like name, id, roll no.

Python Code:

```
            my_cursor = conn.cursor()

            my_cursor.execute("select Name from student where Id=" + str(id))
            n = my_cursor.fetchone()
            n = "+".join(my_cursor)

            my_cursor.execute("select RollNo from student where Id=" + str(id))
            r = my_cursor.fetchone()
            r = "+".join(my_cursor)

            my_cursor.execute("select Id from student where Id=" + str(id))
            i = my_cursor.fetchone()
            i = "+".join(my_cursor)


            if confidence > 77:
                cv2.putText(img, f"Name:{n}", (x, y - 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)
                cv2.putText(img, f"Roll:{r}", (x, y - 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)
                cv2.putText(img, f"Id:{i}", (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 1)

            else:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                cv2.putText(img, "Unknown Face", (x, y - 55), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 255), 3)

            coord = [x, y, w, h]

        return coord

    def recognize(img, clf, faceCascade):
        coord = draw_boundary(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, (255, 25, 255), "Face", clf)
        return img

    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    clf.read("classifier.xml")

    video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, img = video_cap.read()
        img = recognize(img, clf, faceCascade)
        cv2.imshow("Welcome to Face Recognition", img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
            break
    video_cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you could run one `SELECT Name, RollNo, Id ...`

Comment: Maybe you work on copy of image. You didn't show full `draw_boundary`

Comment: maybe you should use `n = "+".join(n)` instead of `my_cursor`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what di you want to get by the code

```
    n = my_cursor.fetchone()
    n = "+".join(my_cursor)
    ...
    r = my_cursor.fetchone()
    r = "+".join(my_cursor)
    ...
    i = my_cursor.fetchone()
    i = "+".join(my_cursor)
```

because `str.join()` should be provided with a iterable of strings as argument to work but `my_cursor` is a Cursor object. Use

```
n = "+".join(n)
```

to get something like "Smith+John" at `n` and etc..

Comment: I did that but it throws an error "n = "+".join(n)  TypeError : can only join an iterable"

Comment: Sure, you should use n = "+".join([n]). My mstake. But it's still unclear what do you want to get by this operatiom.